# Convert string into a time format

Tags: oracle, date, format

In Oracle 11g, how can I convert a string like this "1234" into a time format like this "12:34".

I've tried `to_char('1234', 'HH:MI')` but I get an Invalid number format model.

Comment: Don't call `to_char` on a character string - it's already a string!

Answer (score 3):

Oracle does not have a time data-type.

It has `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data types (both of which have a time component but they also have years, months and days) and it has an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type (i.e. the difference between two `TIMESTAMP`s).

If you want a time with today's date:

```
TO_DATE( '1234', 'HH24MI' )
```

Will output a date with the components:

```
2016-09-06 12:34:00
```

If you want an interval then:

```
NUMTODSINTERVAL( SUBSTR( '1234', 1, 2 ), 'HOUR' )
  + NUMTODSINTERVAL( SUBSTR( '1234', 3, 2 ), 'MINUTE' )
```

Will output the interval with components:

```
+00 12:34:00.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found it:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_DATE ('1234', 'HHMi'), 'HH:Mi') FROM DUAL;
12:34
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_date('1234','hh24mi') from dual;
```

It assumes a date of today with a time component of 12:34